# sql oracle - select availability between dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the below table `INDISPONIBILITY`, that respresents the availability of teachers, for example the teacher a1 is not available from 25-Jan-21 to 25-Jan-21 from 8:00 to 12:00.

I want to select teachers available in a givin date and hour. For example with a date 26-Jan-21 and hour 10:00 the teachers a1 and a2 are not available, but at 12:00 are available.

```
id  endDate    startDate  startHour   endHoure  fk_teacher
1   25-Jan-21  25-Jan-21   800         1200      a1
2   25-Jan-21  25-Jan-21   1400        1600      a1
3   26-Jan-21  26-Jan-21   1000        1130      a1
4   29-Jan-21  28-Jan-21   1200        1400      a2
5   26-Jan-21  26-Jan-21   1000        1130      a2
```

I tried with this query, but in this date 26-Jan-21 and hour 10:00 it returns the teachers a1 and a2.

```
public static String query = "SELECT * FROM ESP_ENSEIGNANT s \n" + 
        "  LEFT JOIN INDISPONIBILITY ds ON ds.fk_teacher = s.teacherId\n" + 
        "  WHERE (?1 NOT BETWEEN ds.STARTDATE AND ds.ENDDATE) AND (?2 NOT BETWEEN ds.startHour AND ds.endHour)";

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = query)
List<TeacherEntity> findAllByUps(Date effectDate, int hour);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a moment to understand why dates and hours are separated in the table. But yes, the teacher a2 is not booked from `2021-01-28 12:00` until `2021-01-29 14:00`, but each day from `2021-01-28` to `2021-01-29` at the hours `12:00` to `14:00`. This makes sense.

We can also observe that `enddate` is inclusive (the teacher is booked on `2021-01-29`) and the hour is exclusive (the teacher is booked until before `14:00`). Another thing to notice is that we are not only talking about full hours here, as there is `11:30` in your sample data.

You want to see if a teacher is available at a certain hour, say `2021-01-26 10:00`. You don't say for how long, so I expect a full hour (i.e. until right before `11:00`). This means, we check the date and see whether the hour falls into their time range. We check the time tables with `NOT EXISTS` or `NOT IN`. As fot the time range we need to check for overlapping ranges. `10:00-11:00` is in the range of `09:00-12:00`, but also overlapping with `09:00-10:30` and `10:30-12:30`

```
select *
from teacher
where teacher_id not in
(
  select fk_teacher
  from timetable
  where :date between startdate and enddate
  and starthour <= :hour + interval '1' hour
  and endhour > :hour
);
```

Comment: I prefer `not exists` to `not in`, but this seems like the correct logic.

Comment: I prefer `NOT IN` for its simplicity, but it's prone to errors. `NOT IN` fails when a null occurs in the list. In your table it would not make sense for an `fk_teacher` to be null, so I consider this safe, but Gordon has a point there.

Comment: I also changed my answer slightly after Gordon's approval, because I noticed that there are half hours in your sample data, so I assume there can be partly overlapping ranges (teacher busy from 10:30-11:00, so 10:00 is not available in case we are talking about the full hour from 10:00 to 11:00 when checking for 10:00).

Comment: in case i have the the end hour (for example teacher available 11:00 to 14:15 ), how can i change the query

Comment: The end hour in my query is `:hour + interval '1' hour`. If you want another end hour, replace this. With `:endhour` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your start_date, end_Date and the date that you will input are date data type, You can use the date operations as follows:

```
select * from your_Table -- teacher - available
 where your_input_date between startdate + (start_hour/2400) and end_Date + (end_hour/2400)
```